# Перенаправление и кодировка

Tags: php

есть одностраничник в котором есть форма по типу "оставить заявку" к которой в свою очередь привязан следующий  php скрипт :

```php
$fio = $_POST['fio'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fio = htmlspecialchars($fio);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($phone);
$fio = urldecode($fio);
$email = urldecode($email);
$phone = urldecode($phone);
$fio = trim($fio);
$email = trim($email);
$phone = trim($phone);
if (mail("...@m....ru", "Заявка с сайта", "ФИО:".$fio. ". E-mail: ".$email. ".phone: ".$phone , "From: ....@.....ru \r\n"))
 {     echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}
header("Location: http://www.......ru/");
exit;
```

1. Впринципе все работает, однако не на всех устройствах сообщение, которое приходит отображается корректно, если человек пишет имя по Русски, то бывает приходит кракозябра. Подскажите решение?
2. Почему не работает редирект через header? Посоветуете некоторое улучшение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Вообще я бы на вашем месте смотрел в сторону PHPMailer, он более вменяемый и гибкий. Что-то вроде [этого](https://medium.com/@shpaginkirill/%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-phpmailer-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-b462f8ff9b5c) почитать (первая ссылка из гугла).

Если оставаться в рамках базовой функции `mail()`, то надо поиграться с заголовками и комбинацией `utf-8` и `base64`.

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
$fio = filter_var(trim($_POST['fio']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_var(trim($_POST['phone']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$from = 'email отправителя';
$recipient = 'email получателя';
$subject = 'Заявка с сайта';

$message = "ФИО: {$fio} \r\n";
$message .= "E-mail: {$email} \r\n";
$message .= "Телефон: {$phone} \r\n";

$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$from} \r\n";

$message = base64_encode($message);
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: http://www.......ru/");
exit;
```

Comment: За наводку спасибо, по второму вопросу не проконсультируете?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ по второму вопросу:
`header()`  не работает, потому что у вас имеется вывод текста перед отправкой заголовка.
Здесь:

```
if (mail("...@m....ru", "Заявка с сайта", "ФИО:".$fio. ". E-mail: ".$email. ".phone: ".$phone , "From: ....@.....ru \r\n"))
 {     echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}
```

Вот [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) подробнее.

Answer (score 0):

1) Не совпадает кодировка сайта и письма, проблема и решение описаны здесь: http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1642065.html#edit86406772

2) Нельзя делать какой-либо вывод на страницу перед выполнением функции `header()`. Если нужен и текст и редирект - можно попробовать сделать редирект через JS.